# Would transactions be committed back to the mainnet by sidechains?

Tags: polygon, sidechain, layer-2, xdai

When an L2 solution such as a sidechain like Polygon or xDai commits back to the Ethereum mainnet at every of its intervals, do the transactions, storage in the smart contracts, and everything that were done on that sidechain get merge back onto the Ethereum mainnet?

In other words, when a sidechain commits to the mainnet, will I be able to find those transactions that were made on that sidechain on the mainnet just like there were done on the mainnet? For example, would those transactions made on the sidechain show up in Etherscan?

If the data aren't being merged back on the mainnet, would that mean my daap is stuck to the sidechain or I lose all the activities made on the sidechain?